# Stack Overflow Tag Usage

Tags: sql, stackexchange

I am trying to efficiently use the SEDE tool to get a list of tags a user has answered questions on, and their stats on each Tag.

My code works for my account in 3185 ms, but if I try to run it on [@jon-skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), user ID (22656) then it times out.

Are there ways to make this more efficient / better code, and allow it to be used for any user ID?

[Stack Explorer Link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/850357/my-tags)

```
-- The tags and scores of my posts
CREATE TABLE #MyPosts (
  _tags nvarchar(250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 
  _score int
);

INSERT INTO #MyPosts
SELECT
  Question.Tags,
  Answers.Score
FROM
  Posts as Answers
INNER JOIN
  Posts AS Question
ON
  Question.Id = Answers.ParentId
WHERE
  Answers.PostTypeId = 2 AND
  Answers.OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int?8041461##;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- All of the tags with the total score and the amount of times used
CREATE TABLE #TagCounts (
  _tagName nvarchar(35) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 
  _score int,
  _count int
);

INSERT INTO #TagCounts
SELECT
  Tags.TagName,
  sum(_score),
  count(*)
FROM 
  #MyPosts
INNER JOIN Tags ON #MyPosts._tags LIKE '%<'+Tags.TagName +'>%'
GROUP BY Tags.Id,Tags.TagName;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Outputs the tags with links, total score, count and average score
SELECT
  _tagName as [TagName],
  _score as 'Total Score',
  _count as 'Answer Count',
  cast(_score as FLOAT) / _count as 'Average Score'
FROM
  #TagCounts
WHERE
  _score IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  _score DESC
```

Comment: What flavour of SQL is this? Why are you creating temporary tables?

Comment: It's the SEDE version of TSQL, I am creating the temporary tables to pass results between the sections, filtering down to try to keep under the timeout limit.

Comment: Please show the results of an EXPLAIN on each of your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `TagName` column holding all the tags is denormalized and the non-equi-join `ON #MyPosts._tags LIKE '%<'+Tags.TagName +'>%'` kills performance. There's no efficient way for the optimizer to do this join, thus it's like a Cross-Join to the 50000+ rows in `Tags`.

But the base data model is normalized, there's an associative table `PostTags` between `Posts` and `Tags` and then it's simple equi-joins:

```
with MyPosts as 
 (
-- The tags and scores of my posts
   SELECT
     Question.Id AS PostId,
     Answers.Score
   FROM
     Posts as Answers
   INNER JOIN
     Posts AS Question
   ON
     Question.Id = Answers.ParentId
   WHERE
     Answers.PostTypeId = 2 AND
     Answers.OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int?8041461##
 )
-- All of the tags with the total score and the amount of times used
SELECT
  t.TagName,
  sum(score) as "Total Score",
  count(*) as "Answer Count",
  cast(sum(score) as FLOAT) / count(*) as 'Average Score'
FROM 
  MyPosts AS p
JOIN PostTags AS pt
  ON p.PostId = pt.PostId
JOIN Tags AS t
 ON pt.TagId = t.Id
GROUP BY t.Id,t.TagName
ORDER BY "Total Score" DESC;
```

Your `HAVING sum(score) IS NULL` is not needed, there's no NULL score.

See [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/851032/1050813/my-tags) which runs fine with John Skeet, too :-)